# jQuery-only toolTip to display DIV content

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I'm trying to use jquery's toolTip to display mouseover content.  But rather than title="..." content, I want it do display a DIV content.  And it should be modular...

This is what I came up with.  It doesn't quite work... it only works for the first instance.

http://jsfiddle.net/5kkgS/1/

```
$(function () {
    $.widget("ui.tooltip", $.ui.tooltip, {
    options: {
        content: function () {
            return $(this).prop('title');
        }
    }
}); 


$('.toolTipHTML').attr('title', function(){
        var ele = $(this).attr('data-ttipcontent');
        return $('.' + ele + '_content').remove().html()
    })


    $('.toolTipHTML').tooltip({
        tooltipClass: "stdTooltip",
        items: '*:not(.ui-dialog-titlebar-close)',
        show: {
            duration: 0,
        },
        hide: { effect: "fade", duration: 100 },
        position: { my: "left top", at: "left bottom" }
    });
});
```

The above code was adapted from the code I found here.  But the example wasn't quite modular enough for my need.
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/get-jquery-ui-tooltip-to-show-div-content

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only works for the first instance because you remove the `div` element that contains the text after the first implicit iteration with `attr`:

```
$('.toolTipHTML').attr('title', function(){
    var ele = $(this).attr('data-ttipcontent');
    return $('.' + ele + '_content').remove().html() // Removed, no longer available!
})
```

If you remove the `remove()` and just query the innerHTML (`html()`), that would solve your problems. However, then you're left with those DIV elements all up in your DOM!

If you don't mind them chilling in your DOM, you could use some CSS and just hide them (which, I would recommend anyway - since they'll show until your script runs...)

If the thought of them chilling there, taking up DOM space, or you potentially see hundreds, maybe thousands of helper div nodes (ok, prob not!), and you'd really like to remove them, then here's a fiddle I threw together:

http://jsfiddle.net/5kkgS/2/

```
(function() {
    var _cache = {};
    $('.toolTipHTML').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('title', function(){
            var ele = $(this).attr('data-ttipcontent'),
                title;
            if (_cache[ele]) {
                title = _cache[ele];
            } else {
                _cache[ele] = $('.' + ele + '_content').remove().html();
                title = _cache[ele];
            }
            return title;
        });
    });

    _cache = undefined;
}());
```

It's wrapped in a self executing function to minimize exposing globals. The script caches the HTML, so that future elements which require the content will use the cached content. You could expand the caching concept with elements themselves (throwing the removed elements into a fragment) that you query against. Both ways would (in theory) improve performance since you're minimizing the need to touch that DOM. Fun stuff!

Comment: Good lord, you guys are pure genius. You made a huge save for me. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It only works on the 1st one because you have remove the content element after the 1st loop. Use hide instead.

```
return $('.' + ele + '_content').hide().html();
```

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/5kkgS/4/